# What is the proper way to register signal handlers in Python?

Tags: python, signals, multiprocessing

I have a python application where I create several new instances of multiprocessing.Process object from a main process in a fashion similar to:

```
    self.my_proc = Process(name='foo', target=self.bar, args=(self.some_var,))
    self.my_proc.daemon = True
    self.my_proc.start()
    ...

    @staticmethod
    def bar(some_var):
       while True:
          do stuff forever
```

I've noticed that If I register a signal handler in the main process before I spawn the child processes that the signal event causes each spawned process to call the signal handler. If I register the signal handler after I spawn the child processes then a signal event only causes the parent process to call the signal handler.

I really only want the main (parent) process to receive the signal handler callback because it's the process that will clean up all the subprocesses. So my program works as I need it to. But my concern is that there is a better (right?) way to handle signals in multi-process Python applications. Is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is nothing to do with Python as such. It reflects the UNIX (Linux) implementation of signals and their behaviour when a process creates child processes (using the `fork` system call). Here's an quote from the manual which explains the behaviour you have noticed:

> A child created via `fork(2)` inherits a copy of its parent's signal dispositions.
>    During an `execve(2)`, the dispositions of handled signals are reset to the default; 
>    the dispositions of ignored signals are left unchanged.

Comment: I believe POSIX `fork` doesn't actually document what happens with signal handlers; it's acceptable to copy them, reset them to defaults, or almost anything else. Of course you can't portably do anything that isn't async-signal safe between `fork` and `exec` anyway, so this doesn't really matter for portable code…

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that recent 3.x gives you at least ways to take more control of this that 2.x doesn't have: you can `fork+exec` child processes instead of just `fork`, and you can do the "fork from a thread" plus `pthread_sigmask` trick that some web servers use on some *nix platforms.

Comment: @abarnert I always end up with additional reading after your comments :) Not that I am complaining.

Answer (score -1):

If it's convenient in your main process (as it seems to be), and if you only care about catching SIGINT, I prefer to catch KeyboardInterrupt rather than installing a signal handler:

```
@staticmethod
def bar():
    try:
        while True:
            # do stuff forever
            pass
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        # Tell subprocesses to shutdown gracefully
        pass
```